# Use variable with Array in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I would like to use a variable which contains an array, so I can use it with `in` filter.

this works:

```
traces
| where cloud_RoleName in ("A", "B")
```

this does not work (syntax error):

```
let cloudRoleNames = ("A", "B");
traces
| where cloud_RoleName in cloudRoleNames
```

I would like to use the array as variable to be able to use the same filter in more joins at once. As a workaround I use the first working variant but it is not ideal. I tried various ways - as well via parsing json but nothing works. Am I missing something obvious? Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let cloudRoleNames = dynamic(["A", "B"]);
traces
| where cloud_RoleName in (cloudRoleNames)
```

Relevant docs:

- [in operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/inoperator)
- [the dynamic data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic)